# Manipulação de JSON

Tags: php, json, array

Possuo o seguinte código:

```
$Json = array();

foreach ($Dados as $ln){
    $Json[label] = $ln['NOME'];
    $Json[value] = $ln['EMAIL'];            
}

echo json_encode($Json);
```

Com isso possuo o seguinte retorno:

```
{"label":"xxxxxxxxx","value":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Gostaria de trazer todos retornos do banco e também retirar as aspas tanto do label como do value.

Resultado esperado:

```
[
  {label:"xxxxxxxxx",value:"xxxxxxxxxxx"}
  {label:"yyyyyyyyy",value:"yyyyyyyyyyy"}
  {label:"zzzzzzzzz",value:"zzzzzzzzzzz"}
]
```

Comment: Só retorna um pq vc sobrescreve o array a cada iteração do foreach ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode resolver isso criando uma variável de indice para agrupar o label e value.

```
$Json = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($Dados as $ln){
    $Json[$i]['label'] = $ln['NOME'];
    $Json[$i]['value'] = $ln['EMAIL'];            
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($Json);
```

Dependendo do caso apenas fazer a atribuição do item atual em uma nova posição do array resolve:

```
foreach ($Dados as $ln){
    $Json[] = $ln;
}
echo json_encode($Json);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado @rray , funcionou perfeitamente.